# Two displays with an exposed filter

Tags: views

I have a view using one exposed form in a block with a couple exposed filters.  I would like the same result set to be used in two displays that have a slightly different format.

1. One of my exposed filters is not being "remembered" from one display to the other, even though the other filter fields are.
2. When I navigate from one display to the other, the problematic exposed filter (a single checkbox) gets rechecked if it was unchecked.
3. It appears that the query is being re-run when I go from display to display.  I don't really want that to happen since I am using the same result set.  I figured the query only should get run when you hit the SUBMIT button, not change displays.

I have tried to use a number of the `hook_views_xxx` functions to set and reset my `exposed_input` array value for the filter field, but I can't seem to get anything to work.  I have also tried using the `$_SESSION` variable for the field to fix it, but no luck.

If I can understand what is supposed to happen with Views, I can keep trying to solve this myself, but I am really stuck and into this about 10 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your view displays, make sure the common exposed filters have the same Filter identifier.  You can find this when you click the filter, and in the "More" fieldset.